# Rename duplicated index values pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains some duplicated index values:

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(6,6), columns = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=6), index = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"})
df1.rename(index = {"C": "A", "B": "E"}, inplace = 1)

ipdb> df1
      2010-01-01  2010-01-02  2010-01-03  2010-01-04  2010-01-05  2010-01-06
 A   -1.163883    0.593760    2.323342   -0.928527    0.058336   -0.209101
 A   -0.593566   -0.894161   -0.789849    1.452725    0.821477   -0.738937
 E   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
 F    1.707686    0.323213    0.048503    1.168898    0.002662   -1.988825
 D    0.403028   -0.879873   -1.809991   -1.817214   -0.012758    0.283450
 E   -0.224405   -1.803301    0.582946    0.338941    0.798908    0.714560
```

I would like to change only the name of the duplicated values and to obtain a DataFrame like the following one:

```
ipdb> df1
     2010-01-01  2010-01-02  2010-01-03  2010-01-04  2010-01-05  2010-01-06
A   -1.163883    0.593760    2.323342   -0.928527    0.058336   -0.209101
A_dp   -0.593566   -0.894161   -0.789849    1.452725    0.821477   -0.738937
E   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
F    1.707686    0.323213    0.048503    1.168898    0.002662   -1.988825
D    0.403028   -0.879873   -1.809991   -1.817214   -0.012758    0.283450
E_dp   -0.224405   -1.803301    0.582946    0.338941    0.798908    0.714560
```

**My approach:**

(i) Create dictionary with new names

```
old_names = df1[df1.index.duplicated()].index.values
new_names = df1[df1.index.duplicated()].index.values + "_dp"
dictionary = dict(zip(old_names, new_names))
```

(ii) Rename only the duplicated values

```
df1.loc[df1.index.duplicated(),:].rename(index = dictionary, inplace = True)
```

However this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.where.html):

```
df1.index = df1.index.where(~df1.index.duplicated(), df1.index + '_dp')
print (df1)
      2010-01-01  2010-01-02  2010-01-03  2010-01-04  2010-01-05  2010-01-06
A      -1.163883    0.593760    2.323342   -0.928527    0.058336   -0.209101
A_dp   -0.593566   -0.894161   -0.789849    1.452725    0.821477   -0.738937
E      -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
F       1.707686    0.323213    0.048503    1.168898    0.002662   -1.988825
D       0.403028   -0.879873   -1.809991   -1.817214   -0.012758    0.283450
E_dp   -0.224405   -1.803301    0.582946    0.338941    0.798908    0.714560
```

And if need remove of duplicated index to unique:

```
print (df1)
   2010-01-01  2010-01-02  2010-01-03  2010-01-04  2010-01-05  2010-01-06
A   -1.163883    0.593760    2.323342   -0.928527    0.058336   -0.209101
A   -0.593566   -0.894161   -0.789849    1.452725    0.821477   -0.738937
E   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
E   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
E   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
F    1.707686    0.323213    0.048503    1.168898    0.002662   -1.988825
D    0.403028   -0.879873   -1.809991   -1.817214   -0.012758    0.283450
E   -0.224405   -1.803301    0.582946    0.338941    0.798908    0.714560

df1.index = df1.index + df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')
print (df1)
    2010-01-01  2010-01-02  2010-01-03  2010-01-04  2010-01-05  2010-01-06
A    -1.163883    0.593760    2.323342   -0.928527    0.058336   -0.209101
A1   -0.593566   -0.894161   -0.789849    1.452725    0.821477   -0.738937
E    -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
E1   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
E2   -0.670305   -1.788403    0.134790   -0.270894    0.672948    1.149089
F     1.707686    0.323213    0.048503    1.168898    0.002662   -1.988825
D     0.403028   -0.879873   -1.809991   -1.817214   -0.012758    0.283450
E3   -0.224405   -1.803301    0.582946    0.338941    0.798908    0.714560
```

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and elegant answer!

Comment: This solution works just as well for an arbitrary column that needs renaming. `df1['col'] = df1['col'] + df1.groupby(['col']).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')`

Comment: If you want all duplicates to be modified, starting from 1 to n (i.e. E1, E2, E3 and not E, E1, E2): This is the solution: df1.loc[df1.duplicated('col', keep=False),'col] = df1.loc[df1.duplicated('col', keep=False),'col] + (df1[df1.duplicated('col', keep=False)].groupby("col").cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

Answer (score 4):

I used jezrael's great answer in this renaming function:

```
def rn(df, suffix = '-duplicate-'):
    appendents = (suffix + df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')).replace(suffix, '')
    return df.set_index(df.index + appendents)
```

then this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9]}, index=['a'+str(i) for i in [1,2,3,3,4,3,5,5, 6]])
rn(df)
```

spits out this:

```
    a
a1  1
a2  2
a3  3
a3-duplicate-1  4
a4  5
a3-duplicate-2  6
a5  7
a5-duplicate-1  8
a6  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Further improvements from @kotrfa [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240940/11671779), we can the function more flaxible using prefix and suffix. This approach also behaves more like when windows file duplicated upon downloads, adding extra  `(n)`. This approach also support inplace operation from `*args` and `**kwargs`.

```py
def rename_duplicates(df, prefix=' (', suffix=')', *args, **kwargs):
    appendents = (prefix
                  + (df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
                  + suffix
                 ).replace(f'{prefix}1{suffix}', '')
    return df.set_index(df.index + appendents, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to rename any duplicate row a column of your dataframe based on its order of appearance. You can just use `df = df.reset_index()` before using the function and set `column='index'` to use this for your index.

```
def rename_duplicates(df, column='column_name'):
    df = df.copy()
    duplicate_rows = df[column].duplicated(keep=False)
    duplicate_indices = df[duplicate_rows].index

    duplicates_df = df.loc[duplicate_indices, :]
    duplicates_df.loc[:, column] = duplicates_df[column] + '_' + duplicates_df.reset_index().index.astype('str')
    df.loc[duplicate_indices, column] = duplicates_df[column]
    return df
```

If you have two entries named 'apple' these will now be 'apple_0' and 'apple_1' etc.