# Pandas. In the attempt to rename duplicated index in data set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying do practically the same as [Rename duplicated index values pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095955/rename-duplicated-index-values-pandas-dataframe) . But when I try to do the answer given. It throws an error.

```
raise TypeError("can only perform ops with scalar values")

TypeError: can only perform ops with scalar values
```

A fragment of my data is in the image.[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6W6K.png)
(sorry for my English)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('alldata.csv')
df.pop('Unnamed: 0')
df=df.sort_values('user_id')
df=df.set_index('user_id')
df.index.where(~df.index.duplicated(), df.index + '_dp')
```

Comment: Your indices are integer, you need to convert them to string before appending '_dp'

Comment: You code doesn't make sense to me.  I cannot infer what you are trying to do.  Please read [mcve] and provide what you expect the results to look like.  Also, please don't use images.  Copy and paste the text representation of your data.

Comment: Vaishali. And How do you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did:
Search for the duplicates using. pd.duplicates()
then I translate to numpy array
Change the duplicates with the indexes
transform again to dataframe.